# Plugin cakephp-imagine-plugin Implementation Error

Tags: cakephp

I am working with cakephp 3.6 and having trouble implementing a plugin (https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin/)

It looks like it should be very simple to implement, but I can't figure it out and I'm probably missing something obvious.

> Call to a member function processImage() on boolean

Per the installation instructions, I added the following code to `config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Plugin::load('Burzum/Imagine');
Configure::write('Imagine.salt', '$ntCdb-nQuImAnht3cC9PF4Q8P-bOXSppm^c3qcq');
```

I have inside src/Model/Table/PhotosTable.php:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class PhotosTable extends Table
{
    public $name='Photo';
    public $tablePrefix = '';
    ...

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Burzum/Imagine.Imagine');
    }
```

Finally, I added to my application's `src/Controller/Controller.php` the simple example function from the plugin's docs:

```
    public function photos($id,$title)    
    {
        $details=$this->Photos->photoDetails($id);

        $imageOperations = array(
            'thumbnail' => [
                'height' => 450,
                'width' => 450
            ],
        );

        $this->Image->processImage(
            BASE_URL.'image/'.$details->photo_name,
            BASE_URL.'image/thumb_'.$details->photo_name,
            [],
            $imageOperations
        );

        // ...
```

Comment: Okay, looks like I'm implementing the salt in the wrong place for a start.

Comment: You've added the behavior to `PhotosTable`, but you're using `$this->Image` instead of `$this->Photos` in your controller action.

Comment: Thank you ndm - that makes sense!

Comment: @ndm Awesome, I really appreciate it - plugin works perfect now. Thank you very much.